# Arduino TCP Server establishes connection with client but does not receive data

Tags: c++, arduino-ide, esp8266

I am trying to send and receive data with the **TCP** server but I am not receiving data.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>

// Parametros de conexion a red WIFI.
const char* ssid = "bits";
const char* password = "12345";

// Start a TCP Server on port 5000
WiFiServer server(5000);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin(ssid,password);
  Serial.println("");
  //Wait for connection
  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
 Serial.println(WiFi.localIP()); // IP

  // Start the TCP server
  server.begin();
}

void loop() {
  TCPServer();
}

void TCPServer () {
   WiFiClient client = server.available();
    if (client) {
      Serial.println("We have a new client");
      Serial.println("Hello, client!");
        if (client.available() > 0) {
            char thisChar = client.read();
            Serial.println("We got data");
            Serial.println(thisChar);
            delay(200);
        }
    }
}
```

**Test Capture**: In the capture it is seen that the code is executed until the following instruction.

```
Serial.println("We have a new client");
Serial.println("Hello, client!");
```

[image: Test rec]

[image: Test sen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by modifying the code

```
void TCPServer () {
   WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if (client) 
  { 
    Serial.println("New Client");

    while(!client.available()&&client.connected())
    {
    delay(1);
    }

    String linea1 = client.readStringUntil('r');
    Serial.println(linea1);
  }
}
```

[image: test2]

Answer (score 1):

You have created a TCP server. You need to connect other clients to it to start data send and receive process between them. If you just simply run this and wait, then you probably won't get anything because nobody is attempting to connect to it.